# Convert value from edit text to byte

Tags: java, android, eclipse, encryption

i've searched a lot now, but i didn't find anything, so i'll ask here.
This is the code i've got a the moment:

```
byte[] valueofet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(valueofet, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

The error Eclipse is giving me:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from EditText to byte[]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Well what would it *mean* to convert an `EditText` to `byte[]`? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You have to collect the value from the `EditText` field first then convert the string you collected to your byte array, `(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);` this line returns an EditText objct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, it seems you're new to JAVA as well.

Use:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
String content = myEditText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:-

```
EditText valueofet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
String value=valueofet.getText().toString();
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

cheers....!
Please let me know if it works or not...!!

Comment: I think it wouldn't work because you can only encrypt something (with base64) using a byte.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go...

```
EditText valueofet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
Byte[] value=valueofet.getText().toString().getBytes();
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but for now It should like this:

```
EditText valueofet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
byte myByte = Byte.parseByte(valueofet.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

myEditText.getString().getBytes();

Comment: \@Satish  The method getString() is undefined for the type EditText

Comment: I mean myEditText.getText().toString().getBytes();